# Sockets Client/Server application doesn't work over internet despite opened port

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp

I've programmed a TCP/IP server with c# .NET Sockets. Using local network it works fine, but when i try to use it over the internet the client can't connect to the server.

I'm sure i've opened my port (14999) in the router and in windows firewall(both, client and server) and i also mapped my computer port 14999 to the one on the router.

Even with this i get "An existing co
nnection was forcibly closed by the remote host." When my client application try to connect over the internet to my server.

There is one thing i noticed .

When i have my server debugging with Visual Studio, and i use http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ to check the 14999 port, the code hits a breakpoint.

I've been stucked with this ours, is there anybody who knows what can i do ?

Thanks a lot everyone!

Here is my client app code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Person
    {
        public string name;
        public int age;
    }
    // State object for receiving data from remote device.
    public class StateObject
    {
    // Client socket.
    public Socket workSocket = null;
    // Size of receive buffer.
    public const int BufferSize = 256;
    // Receive buffer.
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    // Received data string.
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
}

public class AsynchronousClient
{
    // The port number for the remote device.
    private const int port = 14999;

    // ManualResetEvent instances signal completion.
    private static ManualResetEvent connectDone =
        new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static ManualResetEvent sendDone =
        new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static ManualResetEvent receiveDone =
        new ManualResetEvent(false);

    // The response from the remote device.
    private static String response = String.Empty;

    private static void StartClient()
    {
        // Connect to a remote device.
        try
        {
            // Establish the remote endpoint for the socket.
            // The name of the 
            // remote device is "host.contoso.com".
            IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry("MY PUBLIC IP");
            IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);
            Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.Unspecified,
                    SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            for (;;)
            {
                // Create a TCP/IP socket.


                // Connect to the remote endpoint.
                client.BeginConnect(remoteEP,
                    new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
                connectDone.WaitOne();

                User user = new User() { name = "asdfasdfasdf", adress = "asdfasdfas", country = "asdfasdf", email = "example@example.com", locality = "asdfasdf", pass = "asdfasdf", state = "aasdfasd", surname = "asdfasdfasdf", telfNum = 123123 };

                loginPublic login = new loginPublic() { email = "example@example.com", pass = "asdfasdfasdfas" };

                accion accion = new accion() { act = 2, data = login };

                var die = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(accion);

                //string guy = SPHFS.EncryptStringAES(die, "HFSIsAwesome12@.");
                string guy = die;
                // Send test data to the remote device.
                Send(client, guy);
                sendDone.WaitOne();

                // Receive the response from the remote device.
                Receive(client);
                receiveDone.WaitOne();

                respuesta Resp = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<respuesta>(response);
                Console.WriteLine("Message : {0} and Result : {1}", Resp.Message, Resp.Result);
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                // Write the response to the console.

            }

            // Release the socket.

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    private static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete the connection.
            client.EndConnect(ar);

            Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}",
                client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

            // Signal that the connection has been made.
            connectDone.Set();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    private static void Receive(Socket client)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create the state object.
            StateObject state = new StateObject();
            state.workSocket = client;

            // Begin receiving the data from the remote device.
            client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                ReceiveCallback, state);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the state object and the client socket 
            // from the asynchronous state object.
            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket client = state.workSocket;

            // Read data from the remote device.
            int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                // There might be more data, so store the data received so far.
                state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

                // Get the rest of the data.
                client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                    ReceiveCallback, state);
            }
            else
            {
                // All the data has arrived; put it in response.
                if (state.sb.Length > 1)
                {
                    response = state.sb.ToString();
                }
                // Signal that all bytes have been received.
                receiveDone.Set();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    private static void Send(Socket client, String data)
    {
        for(;;)
        {
            try
            {
                // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
                byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

                // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
                client.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
                    SendCallback, client);
                break;
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }


    }

    private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
            int bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);
            Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to server.", bytesSent);

            // Signal that all bytes have been sent.
            sendDone.Set();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    public static int Main(String[] args)
    {
        StartClient();
        return 0;
    }
    public class User
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string surname { get; set; }
        public string adress { get; set; }
        public string locality { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
        public string state { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public int telfNum { get; set; }
        public string pass { get; set; }
        public LicenceDAO licencia { get; set; }
    }

    public class LicenceDAO
    {
        public decimal payment;
        public DateTime nextPayment;
        public bool state;
        public string administrator;
    }

    public class accion
    {
        public int act;
        public string key;
        public object data;
    }

    public class respuesta
    {
        public bool Result;
        public string Message;
    }

    public class loginPublic
    {
        public string email;
        public string pass;
    }



  }
}
```

Comment: When you say `the code hits a breakpoint`, you mean you can see the execution move into the code that accepts a connection? So if an external connection is attempted on your designated port, your server code is getting that much, but your client application does not have the same effect when you try to connect using it instead of a 3rd party tool?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. Thanks for the anwser!

Comment: Can you ping the public address and port from your computer you are attempting to connect with the client from? `ping <public_ip>:<port>`.

Comment: No, i can't ping my public adress :S I think this is the main problem so how can i solve ?

Comment: This is not a problem with your code, it is your routing. What you are trying to do is called hairpin NAT or hairpinning.

Comment: I get this message (translated from spanish it's not the same maybe)  : "Ping request could not find host <public-ip>:<port> Check the name and try again"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having an issue because you are attempting to connect to a server on your local network via the external address using NAT (hairpinning). Normally you should connect to your server application using the internal address if available, external connections would still work using the external address through NAT. If this is just an issue for testing and your router does not support NAT hairpinning, NAT loopback, or NAT reflection, you can either look around for ways to get around the hairpin (usually by setting up your own DNS) or have someone help you test from an external connection.

Comment: Thanks you!! I 've connected another computer to my mobile network and it works now ^^